# Get X/Y position of pixel in PNG file

Tags: image, png, pixel

After stripping off header bytes and de-compressing the pixel values, a PNG file leaves us with a set of rows (a horizontal strip of the image one pixel high).

Each row starts with a single byte specifying the filter used, followed by RGB values:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0:F | 1:R | 2:G | 3:B | 4:R | 5:G | 6:B |    // end of first row in image
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 7:F | 8:R | 9:G |10:B |11:R |12:G |13:B |    // end of second row
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

In an image without the filter byte, I could just divide the index by 3 (since there are three values per RGB pixel), then use these formulas to get the x/y position of that pixel:

```
x = index % width
y = index / width
```

But the filter byte is throwing me off! How do I get the x/y position of a pixel, given a red pixel's byte index? (Say at byte 4 or at byte 11, as shown above.)

I've tried all kinds of permutations but I think there must be an elegant solution!

Comment: You must process each line according to its filter, but after you did that you can throw it away.

Comment: @usr2564301 – yes, but I still need a way to know where a particular pixel goes in the image. I could keep count as the image is decoded, but I want to know the x/y position of an arbitrary pixel

Comment: I was going to put up a long answer explaining *`stride`*, but it seems you only are missing one thing. *Before* dividing by 3, subtract 1 from that starting value. Tha's all.

Comment: @usr2564301 – I feel like I tried that previously but maybe didn't do it right. Wouldn't that throw off the x coordinate? I don't know anything about stride so I'd welcome more info!

Comment: Thanks @usr2564301 – I worked on this some more and I think you're correct. I posted this as an answer below but would be great if you could verify this looks right to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments from @usr2564301, I think this works correctly:

```
y = ((index-1) / 3) / width
x = ((index-y) / 3) % width
```

Where `width` is the width of the image in pixels, not the width of the row of bytes.

We subtract `y` from the `index` because each row has a single filter byte and we need to remove them all to get the `x` position.

Alternatively, `y` can be calculated using:

```
y = index / row_width
```

Where `row_width` is the number of bytes per row: three for `RGB` and one filter byte times the width of the image.

Comment: Yup. But unless you still need that filter (to re-compress the image, for example), you might as well never save it in your pixel stream.

Comment: Hmm, actually I don't think this is right. After a few rows the filter byte starts to add up and creates an error.

Comment: And I got it! For `x` we have to subtract `y` from the index not `1`

Comment: A-ha – you have all of your pixels (and filters) in one continuous stream. Yeah, then this makes sense (you still have to subtract 1 for the very first filter byte as well). I'd still *highly* advise a more structured approach: a list of rows, with only RGB pixel data per row.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on something super weird and need to do it this way – def appreciate the help!